# what does +cont mean in phonological rules

Tags: phonology

One of the solutions in my practice questions for a phonological rule was listed as:

C[+cont, α place] -> [+plosive] / N [α place] ___

to represent a situation where voiced consonants are realised as voiced stops after a nasal

Could someonen clarify what the +cont means?

Answer (score 3):

It refers to [continuants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuant), consonant sounds that don’t have a complete oral closure (and are thus able to have *continuous* voicing or airflow), in contrast to plosives which have a complete oral closure. (Continuants can also be defined as any sound without a complete closure, including vowels, but that would make little sense here, since vowels do not generally become plosives.)

So the rule is saying that any consonant that has a partial, but incomplete, oral closure is ‘closed’ up to have a full closure and thus become a plosive before a nasal consonant at the same place of articulation; for example, /ɣŋ βm ðn/ would become /ɡŋ bm dn/.